# Suppress page numbers for \part titles in memoir

Tags: memoir, page-numbering, parts

I am using `memoir` and I would like the `\part` titles to print without page numbers.  I have used

```
\aliaspagestyle{title}{empty}
```

to do this for the title page, is there a similar command for parts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
```